# How to pass a block of code (and its function scope) to multiple functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I got couple of functions (for example second code sample here (moveLeft)) in js that partially use the same portion of code (prepareMove). 
(code works just fine if i just copy prepareMove inside moveLeft)

**What I want to happen:** event occurs -> prepareMove initiates -> moveLeft initiates (while accessing prepareMove functions scope)

Simply calling prepareMove inside moveLeft causes some scope issues i suppose, as moveLeft cant retrieve values assigned in prepareMove.

How can i adress this scope issue? Is theree something like django's block.super i could use (~passes the code in parent container to child and executes both)? Whats the proper way to approach this issue in javaScript?

```
function prepareMove() {
    var getCurrent = ptPageXYZarray.filter( function (el) {
                return el.isCurrent === true;
            })[0];

    var currentX = getCurrent.x,
        currentY = getCurrent.y,
        currentZ = getCurrent.z,
        currentYmax = getCurrent.yMax,
        currentZmax = getCurrent.zMax;

    var newCurrent = function (a,b,c) {
        newCurrent = ptPageXYZarray.filter(function(obj) {
                      return obj.x == a && obj.y == b && obj.z == c;
                    });
        return newCurrent;
    };

    var outAnimation = function (outAnimationClass) {
        getCurrent.ptPageObj.className += ' ' + outAnimationClass;
        function removeOutAnimation() {
                removeClass(getCurrent.ptPageObj, outAnimationClass);
        }
        setTimeout(removeOutAnimation,700);
    };

    ...
}
```

and there is second function

```
function moveLeft() {
    prepareMove(); //scope issues here?
    if (currentZ === 0 && currentY !== 0) {
            newCurrent(currentX,currentY -1,currentZ);

            outAnimationClass = "mm-page-visible mm-page-moveToRightFade";
            outAnimation(outAnimationClass);

            swapCurrentEls();

            inAnimationClass = "mm-page-visible mm-page-moveFromLeft";
            inAnimation(inAnimationClass);

        } else
        ...
};
```

on event I initiate moveLeft function with

```
moveLeft();
```

work in progress (use arrows): http://www.mymlyn.com//page-templates/css-transitions-keyboard/

bitbucket: [https://bitbucket.org/mymlyn/mymlyn.com/overview][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use an object. `prepareMove` would populate and return the object with all the properties you want, and `moveLeft` would use them.

It is also possible to change the structure somewhat:

```
function effect() {

    // private

    var getCurrent = ptPageXYZarray.filter( function (el) {
            return el.isCurrent === true;
        })[0];

    var currentX = getCurrent.x,
        currentY = getCurrent.y,
        currentZ = getCurrent.z,
        currentYmax = getCurrent.yMax,
        currentZmax = getCurrent.zMax;

    ...

    var r = { };

    // public (everything in r)

    r.left = function( ) {
        if (currentZ === 0 && currentY !== 0) {
            newCurrent(currentX,currentY -1,currentZ);

            outAnimationClass = "mm-page-visible mm-page-moveToRightFade";
            outAnimation(outAnimationClass);

            swapCurrentEls();
            ...
        } ...
    };

    r.right = function( ) {
        ...
    };

    ...

    return r;
}
```

now you can call it like `effect( ).left( )` or `effect( ).right( )`. Just calling `effect( )` alone will do the prep work, but since that doesn't actually do anything it doesn't matter. You can also use private functions and other fancy things.

As for your original question, no, you can't set the scope of a function which you're calling. Only the `this` variable (via `call` or similar).

Comment: this is smart, thank you! added links on bottom of question. works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way  would be  is `return the variables you need as an object or an array` from `prepareMove`.

```
function prepareMove() { 

   var obj= {},
       obj["currentX"]  = currentX;
       obj["currentY"]  = currentY;
       obj["currentZ"]  = currentZ;
   return 
}
```

The access the variable in the other function.
You could have also used the **dot notation here**.

```
function moveLeft() {
    var obj = prepareMove();

    var currentX = obj["currentX"],
        currentY = obj["currentY"],
        currentZ = obj["currentZ"],
```

Comment: I think `obj.["currentX"]` is a typo. Anyway I'd just suggest `obj.currentX`. I guess you're using this syntax because you've been using optimising compilers?

Comment: @Dave. Thanks for pointing it out.. Fixed it. And for your second question.. Not really  :)

Answer (score 1):

If `prepareMove` just assigns a bunch of variables, you could have it return an object containing their values at the end:

```
return {
    getCurrent: getCurrent,
    currentX: currentX,
    // ...
};
```

Then in `moveLeft` you could assign the result to a variable:

```
var v = prepareMove();
```

Then whenever you want to use one of the values, access it in `v`, e.g.:

```
if (v.currentZ === 0 && v.currentY !== 0) {
    v.newCurrent(v.currentX, v.currentY - 1, v.currentZ);
    // ...
```

There's one case in which this won't work, and that's when a function defined inside of `prepareMove` changes one of the variables it closed over. In that case, the change would be visible to all the other functions defined in `prepareMove`, but the change would not be propagated to `v`.

Comment: You could also use `with(v) { /* ... */ }` if you got tired of doing `v.` all the time, but `with` is usually regarded as undesirable.